# Trying to connect Smooth Div Scroll Jquery to my site but its not connecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

Hi I am trying to connect Smooth Div Scroll to my site: http://Izzy.me

Smooth Div Scroll is this: http://smoothdivscroll.com/

In the front page of Izzy.Me I have 3 pictures of birds that I am using as an example to see if Smooth Div Scroll is connected.

This is the CSS of those pictures:

```
    <div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird4.jpg" alt="Field" id="field" />
    <img src="http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird.jpg" alt="Gnome" id="gnome" />
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KFaKPd9ytxM/TxdKjRZulaI/AAAAAAAAD6A/w0kduvREq2w/s1600/bird-1-wallpaper-1024x768-853745.jpeg" alt="Pencils" id="pencils" />
    </div>
```

In my child functions php I have this :

```
    <?php

    function theme_javascript()
    {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'kinetic', get_template_directory_uri() .      '/js/jquery.kinetic.min.js', array('jquery'), '20140109', true );   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js', array('jquery'), '20140109', true );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothdivscroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js', array('jquery'), '20140109', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js', array('jquery'), '20140109', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', array('jquery'), '20140109', true ); 
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_javascript' );


    ?>
```

The file of the plugin that I downloaded from smoothscroll , includes both .min files and the full js files. I just dragged and dropped the .min files into my parent themes JS folder and ignored the more complete .js files in the folder.

I am not sure if my functions code is written right , because the name of the .min files confused me a little as to how to include them correctly. So maybe thats why its not connecting ? the five names of the .min files are :

1. jquery.kinetic.min
2. jquery.mousewheel.min
3. jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min
4. jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min
5. jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min

so looking back now at the functions php i included does it look right ? ( thanks for your help )

Comment: Maybe you should explain what it does and what it should do for you

Comment: Why not just include a link to the div-scroll cdn (//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-smooth-scroll/1.4.13/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js) in your html?

Comment: Also, .min files are just compiled javascript, they are included in the same way that full source files are.

Comment: Chanckjh , an example of what it should do is shown as an example here : http://smoothdivscroll.com/ . you can also see an example on http://www.blacksabbath.com/ .  And rogue_js, should i just then try to include the full js files and delete the .min files? does the file names look right as i included them in my functions php code? ( you can use the list of the five file names as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

debug your javascript:

1. open site in Chrome
2. press F12
3. refresh the page, do you see any errors?

[image]
*Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'widget'* - this error occurs if jQuery.UI is not connected

try to find incompatible libraries:

1. create external working sample, then insert it into site ( http://jsfiddle.net/wnCPL/ ).
2. try to change order of js libraries.
3. try to exclude JS libraries sequentially one after the other
4. replace incompatible library to another similar or different version

sample html:

```
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-B5j3nmGIRLY/Uh3PDcFW1GI/AAAAAAAADmg/6qMAB1d7E4Y/w439-h612-no/DSC_1841-Edit_HDR-v2-w900-RP.jpg" alt="Field" id="field" />
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-5JUmqJ5zOho/Uf5xP9l5LcI/AAAAAAABB-U/dVkkiLJ3_PA/w857-h612-no/In+Living+Color+%25C2%25A9+Laurie+Rubin_LAR3452.jpg" alt="Gnome" id="gnome" />
    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-NNtAD1d_Ekg/UgGad3929uI/AAAAAAAAXxc/oRerem5pkPg/w918-h612-no/Afternoon-2.jpg" alt="Pencils" id="pencils" />
</div>
```

sample javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        touchScrolling: true,
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        hotSpotScrolling: false,
        mousewheelScrolling: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thaks for helping me , when you say "create external working sample, then insert it into site." , how do i do this ? I though thats what i am trying to do now ?  ... does the naming look right in my code ?

Comment: Hi , Thank you for that link. but I dont understand why when I went to the external links it only showed  jquery.min.js,
jquery-ui.css, and jquery-ui.min.js ? When in the downloaded files I see five and there names are --->
  1.) jquery.kinetic.min
  2.) jquery.mousewheel.min
  3.) jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min
  4.) jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min
  5.) jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min   <--- I included the css right now from your link, and even included your pictures as you can see on izzy.me as i am trying to recreate the fiddle you did. So I guess the only thing i am doing wrong is my functions ?